# (Java) Custom made low-level HTTPS get/post request

Tags: java, ssl, https, request, protocols

I'd like to make my own GET/POST request. I can do this when it is HTTP but HTTPS doesn't work for me. I don't want to use HttpURLConnection.

Something I've tried:

```
Socket s = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(new InetSocketAddress("https://www.google.com/", 443).getAddress(), 443);
s.setSoTimeout(60*1000);

String request = "GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
String[] headersArray = headers.split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < headersArray.length; i++) {
    request += headersArray[i] +"\r\n";
}
request += "\r\n";

OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
os.write(request.getBytes("UTF8"));
os.flush();
//etc (reading response)
```

However on writing the request to the outputstream I'm getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

*Note that I want to be able to do this "on the lowest level as possible" so I have as much control as possible and know exactly what is being sent/received. I tried doing this with HttpURLConnection (gotten from a URL object) but it refused to send certain special headers that I gave it.*

**Update: Problem solved.**

Just needed to replace

```
new InetSocketAddress("https://www.google.com/", 443)
```

with

```
new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 443)
```

Kinda strange error though, I would have rather expected to get an error during socket creation from this.

Comment: Can you provide the whole error trace?

Comment: Updated the question body with the whole error trace (down to where I call the write method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("www.google.com", 443);
s.startHandshake();
s.setSoTimeout(60 * 1000);

OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

String request = "GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
os.write(request.getBytes("UTF8"));
os.flush();

String str;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I take it the key difference between what you are doing and Lei Ing Lo was trying is the "s.startHandshake()" ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I actually didn't even need to cast it to SSLSocket and do the handshake, all I had to do was replace "[https://www.google.com/](https://www.google.com/)" with "www.google.com" during socket creation.